# .Net Web Application and Oracle Access Manager Webgate communication

Tags: c#, .net, web-applications, oracle-access-manager

My team has a .Net web application that needs to be able to receive the response from the OAM SSO page.

At our company the team that handles OAM and Webgate only handles the installation to the server and does not handle support for integrating into the application. We have asked for assistance with connecting to Oracle for support and they have indicated they cannot do this. The end result is that we have an IIS server with Oracle's Webgate installed and a functional web application hosted on that server but no ability to tie the two together.

I would show code, but we are at ground zero for this.

Any solution that can help us to be able to get our application to be able to receive the response from the SSO login page would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team eventually found this blog, which does an excellent job of explaining how to setup OAM SSO and a Site on IIS so that they can communicate with each other. It is a little old, but was not that difficult to find the current version equivalents.

[Chuni Lal Kukreja Kubernetes, OAM, OIM, Webgate,Active Directory,SharePoint 2013,IIS7.5,OAAM Blog](https://oracleoam.blogspot.com/2014/08/integrating-oam-11g-r2ps2-webgate.html)